# Pandas Multiple Plotting

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, plot, normal-distribution

I have Dataframes which contains daily returns data for different indices. I am using the below code to plot the Density of the returns distribution.

```
df.plot(kind='density', title='Returns Density Plot for '+ str(i))
```

In the same graph I want to plot the Normal Density curve with the same mean and standard deviation as the Index Returns so that I can see how much the Empirical PDF curve deviates from the Normal Distribution Curve.

What will be the easiest way to do this?
A sample Empirical PDF
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose You could do something like this, assuming you have a data frame column which contains the normal distribution values.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(somefile.csv)
density=df['Density']
norm_density=df['Normal Distribution']
f= figure(1)
f1=plt.plot(density,title='Returns Density Plot for '+ str(i))
f2=plt.plot(norm_density="normal density")
plt.legend(f1[0],f2[0],('density','normal distribution'))
f.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I used something like this and it works

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=mean,scale=std,size=len(dic_2[i])))
ax=df.plot(kind='density', title='Returns Density Plot for '+ str(i),colormap='Reds_r')
df1.plot(ax=ax,kind='density',colormap='Blues_r')
```

[image]